# How to get particular parts of a DateTime object?

Tags: java, jodatime

I have a DateTime object DT which stores current time. When I print DT, I want it to only print the time part, ie HH-MM-SS (H = hours, M = minutes, S = seconds) and ignore the date part.

How can I do this ? For that matter, is it even possible to create a date time object which will only contain HH-MM-SS and nothing related to date ? If that is true, then I can simply print it instead of extracting the HH-MM-SS part.

Thanks.

Comment: FYI, the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want the time, you should use a [`LocalTime`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/LocalTime.html) instead of a `DateTime`. You can use [`DateTime.toLocalTime()`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#toLocalTime%28%29) to get the time part of an existing `DateTime`.

If you actually want to keep the `DateTime` but only reveal the time part when *formatting*, you can create a [`DateTimeFormatter`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) with a pattern which only includes the time parts, but I'd usually consider this a design smell.

Comment: Can we set the time zone when calling toLocalTimeZone ? Or do we get local time and then convert it to desired timezone ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java date formatter which is in java.util.Date package.

Like :

```
  Date todaysDate = new java.util.Date();

  1. // Formatting date into  yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss e.g 2008-10-10 11:21:10
     SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
     String formattedDate = formatter.format(todaysDate);

  2. // Formatting date into  yyyy-MM-dd e.g 2008-10-10 
     formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
     formattedDate = formatter.format(todaysDate);

  3. // Formatting date into  MM/dd/yyyy e.g 10/10/2008 
    formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    formattedDate = formatter.format(todaysDate);
```

Comment: Sorry, thats not what i am looking for. Its Joda Time and not Oracle Java Time.

Answer (score 0):

With Java you can do it like this

```
Date obj = new Date() ;
        System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss").format(obj)) ;
```

but it could be an expensive call. 
But jodatime gives LocalTime which you can try out.

Comment: why do you say its expensive ?

Comment: Couple of reasons : Firstly, It will capture complete data and time and using using SimpleDataFormat it will extract the time and ignore data. Secondly,from stats, Instance creation  SimpleDateFormat  is expensive (time wise) . You can create a Static reference of SimpleDataFormat and use it! but again SimpleDataFormat is not thread safe.  You have to careful, probably declare it as ThreadLocal and use.